Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) notifications not received in Next.js web app (despite working Android app)
I'm facing an issue with Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) notifications in my Next.js web app. I have a working server-side implementation using the Firebase Admin SDK that successfully sends notifications to my Android device. However, I'm not receiving any notifications messages in the web app, the notification popup will be shown but no react state will change thus I can't see the data in the app and therefore, I can't update the messages component with the new info that just came.
Next.js version: 12.3.1
Firebase version: experimented from 7 to ^10
My main firebase configs:
'firebase.js':
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

import { getAnalytics, isSupported } from 'firebase/analytics';
import {
  getMessaging,
  getToken,
  onMessage,
} from 'firebase/messaging';

const firebaseConfig = {
  // firebase config
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig, {
  automaticDataCollectionEnabled: true,
});

const generateFirebaseToken = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Notification.requestPermission().then(permission => {
      if (permission === 'granted') {
        const messaging = getMessaging(app);
        getToken(messaging, {
          vapidKey: process.env.FIREBASE_VAPID_KEY,
        })
          .then(currentToken => {
            if (currentToken) {
              resolve(currentToken);
            }
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log('errror', err);
            reject(err);
          });
      } else {
        reject(new Error('Notification permission not granted.'));
      }
    });
  });
};

let analytics = null;
let token = null;
let messaging;

if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && isSupported()) {
  analytics = getAnalytics(app);
  messaging = getMessaging(app);
  generateFirebaseToken()
    .then(firebaseToken => {
      token = firebaseToken;
      console.log('Firebase token:', token);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.error('Error generating Firebase token:', e);
      token = null;
    });

  console.log('messaging:', messaging, token);
  onMessage(messaging, payload => {
    console.log('Push notification received:', payload);
  });
}

export { app, analytics, messaging, token, generateFirebaseToken };

no logs for onMessage function.
and this is my 'firebase-messaging-sw.js':
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.4/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.4/firebase-messaging.js');

if (firebase.messaging.isSupported()) {
  const firebaseConfig = {
    // firebase config
  };

  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  const messaging = firebase.messaging();

  messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(payload => {
    console.log(
      '[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ',
      payload
    );
  });
}

and in _app.js:
...
import useSWR from 'swr';
...
export default function MyApp(props) {
   ...
   useSWR('/firebase-messaging-sw.js', async () => new Response(), {
      initialData: new Response(),
   });
   ...
}

Troubleshooting steps attempted:
Changed my local host to https for security testing.
Tried different versions of firebase.
different configs for 'firebase.js' and 'firebase-messaging-sw.js'.
Result:
Nothing changed!
